# Using Eloquent in Laravel for more advanced DB queries

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've been developing a laravel application the last couple months and it's my first ride with the framework.  It's also my first time embracing and using an ORM (Eloquent).

For the most part, Eloquent seems pretty straight forward when doing basic DB operations.  However when things get a little more complicated I often find myself spending way too much time trying to figure out how do it the Eloquent way and jump ship to raw db queries.

Was hoping someone might suggest whether or not my desired outcome in the more slightly complicated queries such as the one below should be achievable with Eloquent rather easily, or that I should just keep using raw DB queries.

Tables: **products**, **users**, **alerts**

**alerts** have a `user_id`, a `product_id`, and an `amount` at which the user would like to receive an alert that the product is on sale under a certain price.

Currently I'm using a raw db query to get all the alerts:

```
SELECT p.*, u.firstname, u.lastname, u.email, a.amount AS alert_amount
FROM alerts AS a                                       
JOIN dods AS d ON a.product_id = d.product_id                                        
JOIN products AS p ON d.product_id = p.id                                        
JOIN users AS u ON u.id = a.user_id
WHERE a.amount <= p.saleprice1
```

My eloquent models are set up with relations as follows

**User Model**

```
public function alerts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Alert');
}
```

**Product Model**

```
public function alerts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Alert');
}
```

**Alert Model**

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Product');
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

Thanks for any and all suggestions.
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually ended up being the correct answer I was searching for (off the http://laravel.io/forum and thanks to @onecrush).

```
$alerts = Alert::with(['product','user'])->whereHas('product', function($q){
    $q->where('saleprice1', '<', DB::raw(alert.amount));
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand relationships, you need to understand where the reference should be on the tables.

The alert model has a `belongsTo()` relationship with `User` that indicates the `alerts` table has a field named `user_id` (typically an unsigned int) that holds the related user id.

The user model has a `hasMany()` relationship with `Alert` that indicates the alert table holds the reference as per above.

One user has many alerts, a one to many relationship is established.

You can use this relationship with eloquent for any CRUD operation.

**Some examples to help you along**

*To retrieve all alerts by user*

```
$alerts = User::find(1)->alerts()->get();
```

*To retrieve a user by alert*

```
$user = Alert::find(1)->user()->first();
```

*To insert a new alert against a user*

```
$alert = new Alert(["name" => "alert1"]);

$user = User::find(1);

$user->alerts()->save($alert);
```

*To delete all alerts associated with a user*

```
$user = User::find(1);

$user->alerts()->delete();
```

Comment: Cool.  So that's kind of along the lines of the basic side of things. Really looking to figure out how to get the alerts that match the criteria and include the product and the user tied to that alert.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is many to many relationship:

```
// User model
public function products()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('Product')
     ->wherePivot('amount', '>=', DB::raw('products.salesprice1'))
     ->withPivot('amount');
}

// then
$user->products; // collection of products with price below alerts.amount
```

Comment: Nice.  I'll give this a try and get back to ya.  Seems to be what I'm looking for.